# JBoss String issue

Tags: string, jboss

I have a string in JBoss that contains the word "Protégé" with the accent marks. For some reason JBoss cannot recognize the "e" with the accent marks. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: What does "cannot recognize" mean?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're encoding the String properly; use UTF-8 and Unicode.